# Mystic - how to properly stop an optimization

Tags: python, nonlinear-optimization, mystic

I have a fairly large and complex Python application to which I recently added the ability to perform nonlinear optimization using Mystic (https://github.com/uqfoundation/mystic). The optimization runs in a separate thread from the main (GUI) thread. I am naively using the `fmin_powell` and `diffev` to run the optimization.

Since the evaluation of the objective function can be lengthy, the user has the ability to click on a “stop” button and stop the simulation.

That said, I haven’t found an intelligent way to actually stop the optimization thread, as there seems not be to stop the `fmin_powell` or `diffev` functions. I don’t need to be able to stop the current function evaluation in the middle of the simulation, I would also be happy to wait until the current function evaluation is finished before halting the optimization.

Does anyone know if this is actually possible?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Andrea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm the `mystic` author.  There are two ways, generally.

If you are using the function interface (i.e. `mystic.solvers.diffev2(...)`), then you can use the keyword `handler=True`.  If you do a signal-interrupt, it will pause a running solver that has the handler enabled.  Two things to note: (1) you have to enable the handler when you call the solver, and (2) it may not take effect immediately for solvers running in parallel.

The class interface (i.e. `solver = mystic.solvers.DifferentialEvolutionSolver(...)`) allows you to use the handler (i.e. `solver.enable_signal_handler()`), and/or also you can roll your own solution with `solver.Step()` -- proceed with an optimization asynchronously.   If you use `Step`, it will run only one iteration at a time, so you can then write your own controls for how you want to the solver to progress.

Comment: Thank you Mike. I’ll try the solution with the handler=True and see what happens. I can’t really use Step() as it runs a whole iteration, not a single function evaluation. That said, it would be nice to have a way to say: “look, if the objective function returns NaN, exit the optimization process”. But that doesn’t work in any optimization package I know of, which is a pity as NaN is not a valid objective function value anyway...

Comment: If you are looking to stop when you get a NaN, then you can do that.  Create a termination condition that stops when you get a NaN, and couple it to another termination condition with an `Or`.  See `mystic.termination`.  You'll have to use the solver class interface.